# error starting phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, security, session, phpmyadmin, directory

I have phpmyadmin installed on my development machine

My platform

- windows7 Home premium IIS 7.5
  PHP Version 5.3.4  MySQL Server 5.5
  PhpMyadmin Version 3.4.0-rc1

My php.ini has the following

```
session.save_path = "/temp"
upload_tmp_dir ="/temp"
```

There is a folder named 'temp' in the C:\Windows\ folder and it has full access by IIS users, user(my-computer/users), administrators, and system
I have another named 'temp' folder inside the php folder having the same security setting

But when running phpmyadmin I keep getting this message

```
"Cannot start session without errors, please check errors given in your PHP and/or
 webserver log file and configure your PHP installation properly."
```

I searched the net for this message and no suggestion helped me to come over this

Please help
rema
My php.ini looks like this (I had to remove most of remark to reduce the size )

```
[PHP]
engine = On
zend.ze1_compatibility_mode = Off
short_open_tag = Off
asp_tags = Off
precision    =  14
y2k_compliance = On
output_buffering = 4096
;output_handler =
zlib.output_compression = Off
;zlib.output_compression_level = -1
;zlib.output_handler =
implicit_flush = Off
unserialize_callback_func=
serialize_precision = 100
allow_call_time_pass_reference = Off
safe_mode = Off
safe_mode_gid = Off
safe_mode_include_dir =
safe_mode_exec_dir =
safe_mode_allowed_env_vars = PHP_
safe_mode_protected_env_vars = LD_LIBRARY_PATH
;open_basedir =
disable_functions =
disable_classes =
; ignore_user_abort = On
; realpath_cache_size=16k
; realpath_cache_ttl=120
expose_php = On


;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; Resource Limits ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

max_execution_time = 30     ; Maximum execution time of each script, in seconds
max_input_time = 60 ; Maximum amount of time each script may spend parsing request data
;max_input_nesting_level = 64 ; Maximum input variable nesting level
memory_limit = 128M      ; Maximum amount of memory a script may consume (128MB)


error_reporting = E_ALL

display_errors = Off

display_startup_errors = Off

log_errors = On

log_errors_max_len = 1024

ignore_repeated_errors = Off

ignore_repeated_source = Off

report_memleaks = On

;report_zend_debug = 0

track_errors = Off

;xmlrpc_errors = 0
;xmlrpc_error_number = 0
;html_errors = Off
;docref_root = "/phpmanual/"
;docref_ext = .html

; String to output before an error message.
;error_prepend_string = "<font color=#ff0000>"

; String to output after an error message.
;error_append_string = "</font>"
error_log = errorlog.txt
;error_log = syslog

;arg_separator.output = "&amp;"

;arg_separator.input = ";&"

variables_order = "GPCS"
register_globals = Off
register_long_arrays = Off

register_argc_argv = Off

auto_globals_jit = On

post_max_size = 8M

magic_quotes_gpc = Off

magic_quotes_runtime = Off

magic_quotes_sybase = Off

auto_prepend_file =
auto_append_file =

default_mimetype = "text/html"
;default_charset = "iso-8859-1"

;always_populate_raw_post_data = On


;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; Paths and Directories ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

; UNIX: "/path1:/path2"
;include_path = ".:/php/includes"
;
; Windows: "\path1;\path2"
;include_path = ".;c:\php\includes"

doc_root =
user_dir =

extension_dir = "./"

enable_dl = On

; cgi.force_redirect = 1

; if cgi.nph is enabled it will force cgi to always sent Status: 200 with
; every request.
; cgi.nph = 1

; cgi.redirect_status_env = ;

; cgi.fix_pathinfo=1

; fastcgi.impersonate = 1;

; Disable logging through FastCGI connection
; fastcgi.logging = 0

;cgi.rfc2616_headers = 0


;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; File Uploads ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

; Whether to allow HTTP file uploads.
file_uploads = On

; Temporary directory for HTTP uploaded files (will use system default if not
; specified).
upload_tmp_dir ="/temp"

; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
upload_max_filesize = 2M


; Maximum number of files that can be uploaded via a single request
max_file_uploads = 20

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; Fopen wrappers ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

; Whether to allow the treatment of URLs (like http:// or ftp://) as files.
allow_url_fopen = On

; Whether to allow include/require to open URLs (like http:// or ftp://) as files.
allow_url_include = Off

; Define the anonymous ftp password (your email address)
;from="john@doe.com"

; Define the User-Agent string
; user_agent="PHP"

; Default timeout for socket based streams (seconds)
default_socket_timeout = 60

; auto_detect_line_endings = Off


;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; Dynamic Extensions ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;
; If you wish to have an extension loaded automatically, use the following
; syntax:
;
;   extension=modulename.extension
;
; For example, on Windows:
;
;   extension=msql.dll
;
; ... or under UNIX:
;
;   extension=msql.so
;
;extension=php_bz2.dll
;extension=php_curl.dll
;extension=php_dba.dll
;extension=php_dbase.dll
;extension=php_fdf.dll
extension=php_gd2.dll
;extension=php_gettext.dll
;extension=php_gmp.dll
;extension=php_ifx.dll
;extension=php_imap.dll
;extension=php_interbase.dll
;extension=php_ldap.dll
extension=php_mbstring.dll
;extension=php_exif.dll
extension=php_mcrypt.dll
;extension=php_mhash.dll
;extension=php_mime_magic.dll
;extension=php_ming.dll
;extension=php_msql.dll
;extension=php_mssql.dll
extension=php_mysql.dll
;extension=php_mysqli.dll
;extension=php_oci8.dll
;extension=php_openssl.dll
;extension=php_pdo.dll
;extension=php_pdo_firebird.dll
;extension=php_pdo_mssql.dll
;extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
;extension=php_pdo_oci.dll
;extension=php_pdo_oci8.dll
;extension=php_pdo_odbc.dll
;extension=php_pdo_pgsql.dll
;extension=php_pdo_sqlite.dll
;extension=php_pgsql.dll
;extension=php_pspell.dll
;extension=php_shmop.dll
;extension=php_snmp.dll
;extension=php_soap.dll
;extension=php_sockets.dll
;extension=php_sqlite.dll
;extension=php_sybase_ct.dll
;extension=php_tidy.dll
;extension=php_xmlrpc.dll
;extension=php_xsl.dll
;extension=php_zip.dll

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; Module Settings ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

[Date]
; Defines the default timezone used by the date functions
;date.timezone =

;date.default_latitude = 31.7667
;date.default_longitude = 35.2333

;date.sunrise_zenith = 90.583333
;date.sunset_zenith = 90.583333

[filter]
;filter.default = unsafe_raw
;filter.default_flags =

[iconv]
;iconv.input_encoding = ISO-8859-1
;iconv.internal_encoding = ISO-8859-1
;iconv.output_encoding = ISO-8859-1

[sqlite]
;sqlite.assoc_case = 0

[Pcre]
;PCRE library backtracking limit.
;pcre.backtrack_limit=100000

;pcre.recursion_limit=100000

[Syslog]
define_syslog_variables  = Off

[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
SMTP = localhost
smtp_port = 25

; For Win32 only.
;sendmail_from = me@example.com

; For Unix only.  You may supply arguments as well (default: "sendmail -t -i").
;sendmail_path =

;mail.force_extra_parameters =

[SQL]
sql.safe_mode = Off

[ODBC]
;odbc.default_db    =  Not yet implemented
;odbc.default_user  =  Not yet implemented
;odbc.default_pw    =  Not yet implemented

; Allow or prevent persistent links.
odbc.allow_persistent = On

; Check that a connection is still valid before reuse.
odbc.check_persistent = On

; Maximum number of persistent links.  -1 means no limit.
odbc.max_persistent = -1

; Maximum number of links (persistent + non-persistent).  -1 means no limit.
odbc.max_links = -1

; Handling of LONG fields.  Returns number of bytes to variables.  0 means
; passthru.
odbc.defaultlrl = 4096

odbc.defaultbinmode = 1

[MySQL]
; Allow or prevent persistent links.
mysql.allow_persistent = On

; Maximum number of persistent links.  -1 means no limit.
mysql.max_persistent = -1

; Maximum number of links (persistent + non-persistent).  -1 means no limit.
mysql.max_links = -1

mysql.default_port =

; Default socket name for local MySQL connects.  If empty, uses the built-in
; MySQL defaults.
mysql.default_socket =

; Default host for mysql_connect() (doesn't apply in safe mode).
mysql.default_host =

; Default user for mysql_connect() (doesn't apply in safe mode).
mysql.default_user =

mysql.default_password =

; Maximum time (in seconds) for connect timeout. -1 means no limit
mysql.connect_timeout = 60

; Trace mode. When trace_mode is active (=On), warnings for table/index scans and
; SQL-Errors will be displayed.
mysql.trace_mode = Off

[MySQLi]

; Maximum number of links.  -1 means no limit.
mysqli.max_links = -1

mysqli.default_port = 3306

; Default socket name for local MySQL connects.  If empty, uses the built-in
; MySQL defaults.
mysqli.default_socket =

; Default host for mysql_connect() (doesn't apply in safe mode).
mysqli.default_host =

; Default user for mysql_connect() (doesn't apply in safe mode).
mysqli.default_user =

mysqli.default_pw =

; Allow or prevent reconnect
mysqli.reconnect = Off

[mSQL]
; Allow or prevent persistent links.
msql.allow_persistent = On

; Maximum number of persistent links.  -1 means no limit.
msql.max_persistent = -1

; Maximum number of links (persistent+non persistent).  -1 means no limit.
msql.max_links = -1

[OCI8]
; enables privileged connections using external credentials (OCI_SYSOPER, OCI_SYSDBA)
;oci8.privileged_connect = Off

;oci8.max_persistent = -1

;oci8.persistent_timeout = -1

;oci8.ping_interval = 60

;oci8.statement_cache_size = 20

;oci8.default_prefetch = 10

;oci8.old_oci_close_semantics = Off

[PostgresSQL]
; Allow or prevent persistent links.
pgsql.allow_persistent = On

pgsql.auto_reset_persistent = Off

; Maximum number of persistent links.  -1 means no limit.
pgsql.max_persistent = -1

; Maximum number of links (persistent+non persistent).  -1 means no limit.
pgsql.max_links = -1

pgsql.ignore_notice = 0

pgsql.log_notice = 0

[Sybase]
; Allow or prevent persistent links.
sybase.allow_persistent = On

; Maximum number of persistent links.  -1 means no limit.
sybase.max_persistent = -1

; Maximum number of links (persistent + non-persistent).  -1 means no limit.
sybase.max_links = -1

;sybase.interface_file = "/usr/sybase/interfaces"

; Minimum error severity to display.
sybase.min_error_severity = 10

; Minimum message severity to display.
sybase.min_message_severity = 10

sybase.compatability_mode = Off

[Sybase-CT]
; Allow or prevent persistent links.
sybct.allow_persistent = On

; Maximum number of persistent links.  -1 means no limit.
sybct.max_persistent = -1

; Maximum number of links (persistent + non-persistent).  -1 means no limit.
sybct.max_links = -1

; Minimum server message severity to display.
sybct.min_server_severity = 10

; Minimum client message severity to display.
sybct.min_client_severity = 10

[bcmath]
; Number of decimal digits for all bcmath functions.
bcmath.scale = 0

[browscap]
;browscap = extra/browscap.ini

[Informix]
; Default host for ifx_connect() (doesn't apply in safe mode).
ifx.default_host =

; Default user for ifx_connect() (doesn't apply in safe mode).
ifx.default_user =

; Default password for ifx_connect() (doesn't apply in safe mode).
ifx.default_password =

; Allow or prevent persistent links.
ifx.allow_persistent = On

; Maximum number of persistent links.  -1 means no limit.
ifx.max_persistent = -1

; Maximum number of links (persistent + non-persistent).  -1 means no limit.
ifx.max_links = -1

; If on, select statements return the contents of a text blob instead of its id.
ifx.textasvarchar = 0

; If on, select statements return the contents of a byte blob instead of its id.
ifx.byteasvarchar = 0

; Trailing blanks are stripped from fixed-length char columns.  May help the
; life of Informix SE users.
ifx.charasvarchar = 0

; If on, the contents of text and byte blobs are dumped to a file instead of
; keeping them in memory.
ifx.blobinfile = 0

; NULL's are returned as empty strings, unless this is set to 1.  In that case,
; NULL's are returned as string 'NULL'.
ifx.nullformat = 0

[Session]
; Handler used to store/retrieve data.
session.save_handler = files


session.save_path = "/temp"

; Whether to use cookies.
session.use_cookies = 1

session.cookie_secure ='off';

; session.use_only_cookies = 1

; Name of the session (used as cookie name).
session.name = PHPSESSID

; Initialize session on request startup.
session.auto_start = 0

; Lifetime in seconds of cookie or, if 0, until browser is restarted.
session.cookie_lifetime = 0

; The path for which the cookie is valid.
session.cookie_path = /

; The domain for which the cookie is valid.
session.cookie_domain =

session.cookie_httponly = 

; Handler used to serialize data.  php is the standard serializer of PHP.
session.serialize_handler = php


session.gc_probability = 1
session.gc_divisor     = 1000

session.gc_maxlifetime = 1440


session.bug_compat_42 = 0
session.bug_compat_warn = 1

; Check HTTP Referer to invalidate externally stored URLs containing ids.
; HTTP_REFERER has to contain this substring for the session to be
; considered as valid.
session.referer_check =

; How many bytes to read from the file.
session.entropy_length = 0

; Specified here to create the session id.
session.entropy_file =

;session.entropy_length = 16

;session.entropy_file = /dev/urandom

; Set to {nocache,private,public,} to determine HTTP caching aspects
; or leave this empty to avoid sending anti-caching headers.
session.cache_limiter = nocache

; Document expires after n minutes.
session.cache_expire = 180


session.use_trans_sid = 0

; Select a hash function
; 0: MD5   (128 bits)
; 1: SHA-1 (160 bits)
session.hash_function = 0

; Define how many bits are stored in each character when converting
; the binary hash data to something readable.
;
; 4 bits: 0-9, a-f
; 5 bits: 0-9, a-v
; 6 bits: 0-9, a-z, A-Z, "-", ","
session.hash_bits_per_character = 5

url_rewriter.tags = "a=href,area=href,frame=src,input=src,form=fakeentry"

[MSSQL]
; Allow or prevent persistent links.
mssql.allow_persistent = On

; Maximum number of persistent links.  -1 means no limit.
mssql.max_persistent = -1

; Maximum number of links (persistent+non persistent).  -1 means no limit.
mssql.max_links = -1

; Minimum error severity to display.
mssql.min_error_severity = 10

; Minimum message severity to display.
mssql.min_message_severity = 10

; Compatibility mode with old versions of PHP 3.0.
mssql.compatability_mode = Off

; Connect timeout
;mssql.connect_timeout = 5

; Query timeout
;mssql.timeout = 60

; Valid range 0 - 2147483647.  Default = 4096.
;mssql.textlimit = 4096

; Valid range 0 - 2147483647.  Default = 4096.
;mssql.textsize = 4096

; Limits the number of records in each batch.  0 = all records in one batch.
;mssql.batchsize = 0

; Specify how datetime and datetim4 columns are returned
; On => Returns data converted to SQL server settings
; Off => Returns values as YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss
;mssql.datetimeconvert = On

; Use NT authentication when connecting to the server
mssql.secure_connection = Off

; Specify max number of processes. -1 = library default
; msdlib defaults to 25
; FreeTDS defaults to 4096
;mssql.max_procs = -1

; Specify client character set. 
; If empty or not set the client charset from freetds.comf is used
; This is only used when compiled with FreeTDS
;mssql.charset = "ISO-8859-1"

[Assertion]
; Assert(expr); active by default.
;assert.active = On

; Issue a PHP warning for each failed assertion.
;assert.warning = On

; Don't bail out by default.
;assert.bail = Off

; User-function to be called if an assertion fails.
;assert.callback = 0

; Eval the expression with current error_reporting().  Set to true if you want
; error_reporting(0) around the eval().
;assert.quiet_eval = 0

[COM]
; path to a file containing GUIDs, IIDs or filenames of files with TypeLibs
;com.typelib_file =
; allow Distributed-COM calls
;com.allow_dcom = true
; autoregister constants of a components typlib on com_load()
;com.autoregister_typelib = true
; register constants casesensitive
;com.autoregister_casesensitive = false
; show warnings on duplicate constant registrations
;com.autoregister_verbose = true

[mbstring]
; language for internal character representation.
;mbstring.language = Japanese

; internal/script encoding.
; Some encoding cannot work as internal encoding.
; (e.g. SJIS, BIG5, ISO-2022-*)
;mbstring.internal_encoding = EUC-JP

; http input encoding.
;mbstring.http_input = auto

; http output encoding. mb_output_handler must be
; registered as output buffer to function
;mbstring.http_output = SJIS

; enable automatic encoding translation according to
; mbstring.internal_encoding setting. Input chars are
; converted to internal encoding by setting this to On.
; Note: Do _not_ use automatic encoding translation for
;       portable libs/applications.
;mbstring.encoding_translation = Off

; automatic encoding detection order.
; auto means
;mbstring.detect_order = auto

; substitute_character used when character cannot be converted
; one from another
;mbstring.substitute_character = none;

; overload(replace) single byte functions by mbstring functions.
; mail(), ereg(), etc are overloaded by mb_send_mail(), mb_ereg(),
; etc. Possible values are 0,1,2,4 or combination of them.
; For example, 7 for overload everything.
; 0: No overload
; 1: Overload mail() function
; 2: Overload str*() functions
; 4: Overload ereg*() functions
;mbstring.func_overload = 0

; enable strict encoding detection.
;mbstring.strict_detection = Off

[FrontBase]
;fbsql.allow_persistent = On
;fbsql.autocommit = On
;fbsql.show_timestamp_decimals = Off
;fbsql.default_database =
;fbsql.default_database_password =
;fbsql.default_host =
;fbsql.default_password =
;fbsql.default_user = "_SYSTEM"
;fbsql.generate_warnings = Off
;fbsql.max_connections = 128
;fbsql.max_links = 128
;fbsql.max_persistent = -1
;fbsql.max_results = 128

[gd]
; Tell the jpeg decode to libjpeg warnings and try to create
; a gd image. The warning will then be displayed as notices
; disabled by default
;gd.jpeg_ignore_warning = 0

[exif]
;exif.encode_unicode = ISO-8859-15
;exif.decode_unicode_motorola = UCS-2BE
;exif.decode_unicode_intel    = UCS-2LE
;exif.encode_jis =
;exif.decode_jis_motorola = JIS
;exif.decode_jis_intel    = JIS

[Tidy]
; The path to a default tidy configuration file to use when using tidy
;tidy.default_config = /usr/local/lib/php/default.tcfg

; Should tidy clean and repair output automatically?
; WARNING: Do not use this option if you are generating non-html content
; such as dynamic images
tidy.clean_output = Off

[soap]
; Enables or disables WSDL caching feature.
soap.wsdl_cache_enabled=1
; Sets the directory name where SOAP extension will put cache files.
soap.wsdl_cache_dir="/temp"
; (time to live) Sets the number of second while cached file will be used 
; instead of original one.
soap.wsdl_cache_ttl=86400

; Local Variables:
; tab-width: 4
; End:
```

Comment: Did you check your "PHP and/or webserver log file"?  What did they say?  Can you post the output here, if you don't understand what it means?

Comment: where are they, I searched my php folder, IIs menu and wwwroot , could not find what could be a log file

Comment: @Omar S. Al-Abdullatif - search the Apache configuration file for the ErrorLog directive, which will tell you where the error log files are located.

Comment: @AJ - error_log has no value I changed it to "errorlog.txt" I restart phpmyadmin 

The file has these lines
20-Apr-2011 21:08:31 PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library './php_mcrypt.dll' - The specified module could not be found.
 in Unknown on line 0
20-Apr-2011 21:08:32 PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library './php_mcrypt.dll' - The specified module could not be found.
 in Unknown on line 0

I stop php_mcrypt.dll by simicolon 
restart phpmyadmin
the log file is empty

Comment: @Omar S. Al-Abdullatif - sorry just noted that you specified IIS in your original question, my apologies.  Please read this information on installing/configuring the mcrypt extension for PHP:  http://php.net/manual/en/mcrypt.installation.php

Comment: @AJ - Thank you
I am not that expert to be able to use this and compile the PHP, I actual installed pre compiled version of PHP as I mentioned earlier. What I did instead I just download the file php_mcrypt.dll from internet and uncomment corresponding extension line in php.ini
Now when I run phpmyadmin my error log file is empty and still phpmyadmin dos not work

Comment: @Omar S. Al-Abdullatif - no worries...we'll figure this out!  So, what directory did you put php_mcrypt.dll in?  Also, did you restart IIS after you installed the dll & changed php.ini?  I believe you would need to restart in order for both of those changes to take effect.

Comment: @AJ

Q - What directory did you put php_mcrypt.dll in?
A- C:\PHP\ext and my php.ini pointing there
Q- Did you restart IIS after you installed the dll & changed php.ini?
A- Yes, using IIS menu restart option
For the machine I did not restart it

Comment: @Omar S. Al-Abdullatif - sorry, just now getting back to this.  can you edit your original question and paste the entire contents of your php.ini file there?

Comment: @AJ - do you mean as a coment or new quastion?

Comment: @Omar S. Al-Abdullatif - click edit above on **this** question and add the additional info there.  Don't worry about formatting...if it's really messed up I can fix it :)

Comment: @AJ The file was too big to fit so I had to remove some of commented lines

Comment: @Omar S. Al-Abdullatif - you said in a previous comment that your php.ini file was pointing to C:\PHP\ext.  Where do you see this in your php.ini?  What I see is:  extension_dir = "./"  Try changing that to extension_dir = "C:\PHP\ext", restart your IIS, and see what happens.

Comment: @AJ - yes you are right, I changed it just now, restart even the machin but without luck. I do not think that was the reason otherwise i might get errors related to loading the libraries

Comment: still did not solve my problem

Comment: @AJ the selution can be found here http://wiki.phpmyadmin.net/pma/session.save_path I had to correct the bath for session.save_path in the php.ini file  thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

I've found a possible solution to your continuing issue:

[This discussion post](http://www.weberforums.com/topic12882.html?sid=0869569791ab923145ea4b57a5f27514#p35617) mentions that php_mcrypt.dll has a dependency on another dll called libmcrypt.dll.  Please make sure you have this installed.  If libmcrypt.dll is not already installed, you can follow the steps [at this site](http://www.landpro.com.au/Windows_7_Install_mcrypt_extension_and_libmcrypt_dll_for_PHP.php) to add this feature in through the Windows installer.

Comment: Dear AJ

Welcome back to my problem and thank you for your concern
Guss what, it has not been solved yet
I visited the post you suggested and
1- the error message receved by "amanda099" is deferant from mine
2- however I found that I do not have libmcrypt.dl and downloaded it and placed it in my PHP root folder but No luck

To refresh the case, the error message I receve whin I run phpmyadmin is

"phpMyAdmin - Error
Cannot start session without errors, please check errors given in your PHP and/or webserver log file and configure your PHP installation properly."